# syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -q pspew@8.76.82.179 exit
test=$?
echo "return value  is $test"
if [ $test -eq 127 ] ; then
    echo "welcome"
fi
```

When ever i execute the script I get the $test and get few error lines

Syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Comment: This answer may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841235/why-do-i-get-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-do

Comment: This script works for me(on my server obviously)

Comment: @Schleis, it worked exactly the wyas is mentioned in the above url which you have shared

Answer (score 2):

the code

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no -q pspew@8.76.82.179 exit
test=$?
echo "return value  is $test"
if [ $test -eq 127 ] ; then
echo "welcome"
fi
```

has not syntax error
you can put "set -vx" in second line of your script and see what happens